# Issue with javascript rotating background image covering up text box in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a rotating background image with a text box overlaying the bottom portion of the background image. I thought I had everything working perfectly, and then I checked IE. There, the rotating background is on top of the text box, cutting off the top portion. I've tried multiple attempts at z-index, but nothing seems to fix it. It looks fine in safari, chrome and firefox.

I'm happy to provide source code, but not sure if the issue is with my css, the script, or the html...

URL is http://awaybug.com

Comment: Are you adding the background container to the html after the textbox?

Comment: The background container is before the text box in the html.

Comment: Ok, just solved it... didn't have a valid doctype as my first line of code. That fixed it! Thanks Dylan for your time:)